# It is possible to change the colors of hypertext links?

Tags: feature-request, design

While on SO, the hyperlinks are light blue and easy to distinguish from simple text, the hyperlinks on Programmers.SE appears visually as much darker, especially for visited links (due to their color).

[image: Comparing text colors]

Not only do I have some pain to make the difference between visited links and text on my home PC, but with some screens in some working conditions, **it is completely impossible to find a visited link in a text**, and very hard to find non visited links.

Is it possible to make those colors, especially the one used for visited links, lighter?

Comment: Related: [accomodations for visually impaired](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/accomodations-for-visually-impaired)

Answer (score 10):

I've asked the crowd over at [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14194/colour-of-links-on-programmers-stack-exchange) about our link colours, and they seem to agree that our colour scheme is pretty poor.

So it's not just you, and I think the issue is worth revisiting.

Comment: +1: I like the subtlety of our theme, but I do think it's not the best in terms of readability.

Answer (score 2):

I noted that over at [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22824/why-not-rsa-encrypt-the-entire-document) they actually include the underlines on the links and that makes them much easier to pick out of a document.  We really do need to fix the links on programmers.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Change the appearance of Programmers.SE for everyone based on your particular setup? Unlikely.

However, it's easy enough to change it just for you. What's your browser, version, and platform? There's a million different ways to do this, and they all depend on exactly which browser you're running.

Comment: I doubt that I'm the only one having this problem. I have nothing special with my setup, and I really doubt that all monitors I used are the darkest monitors then those used by any other Programmers.SE user. That's why I submitted it to meta, rather then modifying it myself.

Comment: I would *love* to get any suggestions you have for modifying *my* setup (IE9 on Win 7). If you'd care to, you could post your answer here, or over on my [version of this question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/accomodations-for-visually-impaired)