# accomodations for visually impaired

Tags: support, feature-request, design

I am (marginally) color-blind and have great difficulty distinguishing between hyperlinks and normal text on the SE-Programmers site. I can barely tell when the text is actually a link. To my eyes, there just isn't enough visual contrast. (Unlike on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), for instance, where the blue links stand out vividly to me. For that matter, the orange(?)-colored links on this meta-page are easily distinguishable as well.) Can anyone suggest a workaround for this situation (for example, a browser-hack of some sort)?

Note: I am (unfortunately) obliged to use IE at work, so no non-IE browser-specific workarounds will suffice.

**Update:** As Yannis pointed out, my question is very similar in nature to [this question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/it-is-possible-to-change-the-colors-of-hypertext-links), but in my case, I'm not asking for a global site-wide change (though that would be nice), but rather just a workaround for my own setup.

Comment: related: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/it-is-possible-to-change-the-colors-of-hypertext-links

Comment: Well for others having this problem there's [Chrome Daltonize](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/efeladnkafmoofnbagdbfaieabmejfcf) but I'm not aware of IE having any such plugin. Unfortunately Chrome Daltonize isn't nearly as accurate as [Chrometric](http://enably.com/chrometric/), a separate browser. Daltonize seems to only affect images, and breaks sometimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fairly easy to accomplish using IE's *Accessibility* options in *Tools » Internet Options » General » Accessibility*. If you follow the instructions to the letter, results look as blindingly amazing as this:

> [image: Screenshot after settings applied]

Create a file named `userstyle-programmers.css` and enter the following contents:

```
.question-page .post-text a {
text-decoration: underline !important;
color: orange !important;
}
.question-page .post-text a:hover {
color: yellow !important;
}
```

Select it in the aforementioned dialog under *User style sheet* and save.

> [image: Screenshot of settings dialog]

---

Now, one downside to this is that is it applied to all sites. While the CSS is probably restrictive enough to only actually apply the style to SE sites, it'll get applied to [all of them](https://superuser.com/questions/419070/transatlantic-ping-faster-than-sending-a-pixel-to-the-screen).

> [image: Screenshot of SU with same style applied]

To prevent this, create a new file named e.g. `userstyle-switcher.css` with the following contents that are actually a script executed for every `html` element loaded. Not as nice as domain selection in Greasemonkey, but at least it works.

```
html {
   behavior:expression( (function(el){
   var _doc = el.document;
   if(_doc.location.host.toLowerCase() == 'programmers.stackexchange.com') {
     var elmLink = _doc.createElement('link');
     elmLink.rel='stylesheet';
     elmLink.type='text/css';
     elmLink.href= 'file://C:/Users/Daniel Beck/Documents/userstyle-programmers.css';
     _doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(elmLink);
   }

   el.runtimeStyle.behavior = 'none';
  })(this));
}
```

Of course, replace `C:/Users/Daniel Beck/Documents/userstyle-programmers.css` with wherever you saved the other user style sheet file. Remember to use forward slashes and specify the actual path on disk, not what Explorer shows you (so no *My Documents* on e.g. Windows 7). Save, and select *this file* as the user style sheet for IE. The script will get execute on every web page, but the other CSS file will only get loaded when on `programmers.stackexchange.com`.

Most of the "CSS" used in the switcher script is from [here](http://wiki.bit-hive.com/ie_user_css/), but I have no idea what that page says around the code.

Comment: Extremely clever and very useful suggestion -- thank you! Unfortunately, the switcher script is not working for me, and I'm not sure how to "debug" it. When I select the userstyle-switcher.css, there is no effect. I suspect my workstation has user scripts disabled or something, and I don't know how to change that setting.

Comment: @kmote Note that you need to reload the page after setting it. The effect is not immediate as for the other.

Comment: Re-loading didn't help, but I'll select your answer anyway because your first suggestion is so useful.

Comment: @kmote What browser version, OS? It worked like a charm on Windows 7.

Comment: @kmote I've pinged Stack Exchange about your question, I don't know if there's much they can do or if they'll treat this as a priority item (lately we've been pestering them to build us a _lot_ of stuff).

Comment: @DanielBeck - I'm using IE9 on Win7, but it is locked down pretty tightly by employer, so they may have turned off something.

Comment: @YannisRizos: thanks!